# Getting Error (To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools...) after upgrading to SQL 2012 from SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012..  SQL Server Integration Services 11 is installed on the new server.

The package update went fine and runs in BIDs. The package runs fine when executed from Integration Services. The error happens when the package is kicked off from a JOB.

The error happens in the 1st step of the package where it determines the date (written in VB)  The error is the following..

> Code: 0xC000F427     Source: Determine snapshot date
>   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Determine snapshot date of Integration Services or higher. End Error
>   DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).

Does anyone have a workaround?

BTW, I'm finding some packages run fine, from a job, but others are bombing because of this same/similar error ...

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the Job agent is running that package under 64 bit mode.

Comment: Do you have Integration Services installed on that machine?